# Passing variable from shell script to sql statement

Tags: sql, unix, shell, scripting, variables

I was trying to make cat1.txt as a variable ($2) so that it will be inserted in sql select statement. Is there a way to do this?

```
my cat1.txt
1111
2334
2234
3333
4444
....
....
etc.
```

my SQL Statement

```
set echo off linesize 280 pagesize 0 newpage 0 feedback 1 verify off head off    trimspool on
alter session set sort_area_size=104857600;

define filename = &1

spool &&filename
prompt DATE TIME Service Name Amount

select trim(to_char(trans_time,'yyyymmdd')) || chr(9) ||
   trim(to_char(trans_time,'hh24miss')) || chr(9) ||
   trim(prod_name)|| chr(9) ||
   (prod_price)
where m_date = 11 and day >= 23 and day <= 30
and (prod_bill) in ('1111','2334','2234','3333','4444')
/
spool off
exit
```

I want to try this,please see below. Instead of manually typing the prod_bill make it as variable like the filename. Anything I should add to my shell script? Thanks :-)

```
from prod_trans
where m_date = 11 and day >= 23 and day <= 30
and (prod_bill) in ($2)
```

MY SHELL SCRIPT

```
#!/bin/sh

export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_SID=prod
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/9.2.0
export ORACLE_BASE ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/java1.5/bin
export USERNAME=prods
export PASSWORD=prods
export OUT_PATH=/home/prod/reports/adhoc/REp
export SCRIPT=$OUT_PATH/BICScripts/Translog
export OUTPUT=/home/prod/reports/adhoc/REp/Scripts/log/OUTPUT
export FILENM=$OUTPUT/log_`date +%y%m%d`.txt
sqlplus -s $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$ORACLE_SID @$SCRIPT/log.sql $FILENM
```

Comment: Did you found any way?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
v_var=$1
sqlplus -S system/manager << EOF`enter code here`
SELECT username, account_status, expiry_date
FROM dba_users WHERE lower(username)=lower('$v_var');
exit;
EOF
```

hope it solves the problem and i answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea whether there is any way to access Oracle db from shell script, but can you use for example Perl? I imagine this would be quite easy to do using [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm) to access the db.

Of course you could just parse the .sql -file using shell script to add the prod_bills from cat1.txt straight to it.